# Error when create react native project with command 'npx react-native init AwesomeProject'

Tags: react-native

trying to create a react native project by 'npx react-native init AwesomeProject' command
it gives me this error: '/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/npm/react-native: 11: exec: node: not found'

i try to uninstall with this 'npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli' command
but nothing changes.

node is installed and in System variables there is already a path named 'C:\Program Files\nodejs'